# React useEffect not re-rendering functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am passing an access token into a functional component as props. I need the functional component to re-render when the access token has change. I am using useEffect to setState when said access token has change. It is not re-rendering as expected.

```
const Panel = (props) => {

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setAccessToken(props.accessToken)
  }, [props.accessToken])

  return (...)
}
```

Expected: Panel re-render after props.accessToken changes.

Actual: Panel does not re-render with updated props.accessToken value.

Comment: Everything looks good with your code. Can you provide a
[reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you verified that a defined value for `accessToken` is passed to `Panel`? ie, a value that is not `''` as per the inital state?

Comment: @DacreDenny How would I verify that in Panel? I tried console log in the useEffect and it returns null for accessToken. accessToken value is defined in the parent component by an api call which sets the token value with "this.accessToken = response.data". Then, <Panel accessToken={this.accessToken} />

Comment: If you add `console.log("props.accessToken=", props.accessToken)` before the line with `useState`, what is logged?

Comment: @DacreDenny Access token is always null. Is it because I am using this.accessToken in the parent component so updated value is not being passed down?

Comment: Please show the source code where `<Panel/>` is rendered

Comment: I cannot post source code due to company policy. However, in the parent component instead of setting access token value to this.accessToken, I set the access token value to state. That seems to solve the problem. So does this mean component variable changes is not passed down to child component unless it is a state variable?

Comment: @Joseph, you are correct, instance variable's do not help in component re-rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment,

*accessToken value is defined in the parent component by an api call which sets the token value with "this.accessToken = response.data". Then, `<Panel accessToken={this.accessToken} />`*

**Component do not re-render based on local instance variable, in your case `this.accessToken`.**

You need to actually set the token in state, and then pass it to child component.

```
this.setState({accessToken : response.data})
```

And then pass it from state,

```
<Panel accessToken={this.state.accessToken} />
```